# how to make middle div inside scrollable div stay on top when scrolling

Tags: html, menu

I have a header (div), menu (div) & content (div) inside a container (scrollable div).

I'd like to set menu to stay at top of container only when scrolling down inside of the container (scrollable div)!!!.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="LangBar"/>
  <div id="LeftFloat"/>
  <div class="main" id="sb">**this is the CONTAINER (SCROLLABLE DIV)**
    <div id="header">**this is the HEADER (DIV)**</div>
    <div id="menu">**this is the MENU (DIV)**</div>
    <div class="section">**this is the CONTENT (DIV)**</div>
    <div id="footer"/>
  </div>
  <div id="RightFloat"/>
</div>
```

HERE IS MY [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sKPSY/55/)

Comment: You can use position: fixed;top:0; for you menu div to make it fixed on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/aisinvon/4pEBm/5

Because you need menu stick only when scroll down, we can use jquery to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .section {
        height:1000px;
        background: #ccc;
    }
    .main{
        height: 500px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    .fixed {
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="LangBar" />
        <div id="LeftFloat" />
        <div class="main" id="sb">**this is the CONTAINER (SCROLLABLE DIV)**
            <div id="header">**this is the HEADER (DIV)**</div>
            <div id="menu">**this is the MENU (DIV)**</div>
            <div class="section">**this is the CONTENT (DIV)**</div>
            <div id="footer" />
        </div>
        <div id="RightFloat" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $menu = $('#menu'),
                menuTop = $menu.offset().top;
            $('#sb').scroll(function() {
                var scrollTop = $('#sb').scrollTop();
                if (scrollTop > menuTop) {
                    $menu.addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    $menu.removeClass('fixed');
                }

            });
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this works only when you scroll the whole page not just inside the container div ...

Comment: @john_zizou Sorry. If you want to stick one elements on page, you need use position fixed. However fixed element is only working related to body element.

Comment: so there is really no way to make it stuck on top of the page, while scrolling only inside of "CONTAINER"? :( damn, do you have any idea how to make it work so it LOOKS GOOD pls, any suggestions highly appreciated

Comment: sorry but idk what am i doing wrong this time, lame on me. could you pls apply it on this: http://jsfiddle.net/sKPSY/55/ ? i just cant get it to work

Comment: everything done as you, an here is the result: http://highclassgastro.ic.cz/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position the 3 elements and set overflow:auto for the middle one like in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/majinnaibu/p47mU/

CSS

```
html, body, #wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper{
    background: #0f0;
}

#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

#footer{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        Header Content
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus convallis neque ut turpis volutpat pretium. Donec luctus vel lectus eget condimentum. Aliquam interdum dignissim neque, eu pulvinar erat porta sit amet. Nam urna lectus, rhoncus eu ante ac, lobortis pretium velit. Phasellus vestibulum quam in elit dapibus imperdiet. Integer lobortis nec dolor sit amet accumsan. Sed nec faucibus mi, scelerisque mollis erat. Vivamus eu sapien ornare, posuere mi nec, mollis metus. Aenean convallis est ipsum, eget dignissim leo tincidunt eget. Praesent malesuada dolor vel lacus malesuada, at fermentum nunc eleifend. Integer est metus, dapibus sit amet enim in, posuere aliquam lorem. Vivamus convallis neque at odio convallis, ut sodales erat ultricies. Quisque et enim ac enim imperdiet consectetur. Etiam eget lectus nec lorem congue dictum. Nulla facilisi.

        Quisque ligula dolor, pharetra et ante nec, blandit interdum risus. Mauris ultrices malesuada sem, a luctus diam auctor in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque purus magna, laoreet id malesuada non, blandit sed diam. Vivamus blandit faucibus mattis. Aliquam semper faucibus erat eu mollis. Donec eleifend leo lacus, sed aliquet nisi consequat ac.

        Morbi dictum pharetra feugiat. In nec turpis dolor. Mauris consectetur hendrerit scelerisque. Aenean eleifend dui ac augue varius porttitor at a leo. Fusce semper mollis vulputate. Praesent libero enim, congue eget tellus vitae, mattis tempor turpis. Fusce cursus ligula quam, eget iaculis leo ullamcorper eget. Nam laoreet quam pulvinar, egestas justo id, cursus eros. Pellentesque congue porttitor pretium.

        Suspendisse mattis sapien sed magna tempus ultrices. Nullam porta sagittis nulla ut venenatis. Nulla faucibus elementum elementum. Integer sed consectetur elit, quis elementum dolor. Donec dapibus aliquam orci eu pretium. Aliquam vel fermentum nunc. Duis augue mauris, semper at neque ac, aliquet mattis augue. Suspendisse pulvinar vehicula semper. Aenean purus orci, pharetra vel sollicitudin quis, tincidunt ac dolor.

        Duis nibh tellus, iaculis vel venenatis sed, condimentum ac est. Sed ac imperdiet neque. Phasellus et euismod lorem. Nunc hendrerit orci mattis, tincidunt quam vel, varius mauris. Phasellus venenatis malesuada congue. Nam ut nunc eros. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque facilisis massa a tortor imperdiet ullamcorper eget convallis nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Nam a congue est. Praesent id ante dui. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed eget metus sit amet arcu pellentesque molestie ac eget mauris. Nullam adipiscing odio at interdum porttitor. Proin magna mi, facilisis ac rhoncus ac, gravida ut lacus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus convallis neque ut turpis volutpat pretium. Donec luctus vel lectus eget condimentum. Aliquam interdum dignissim neque, eu pulvinar erat porta sit amet. Nam urna lectus, rhoncus eu ante ac, lobortis pretium velit. Phasellus vestibulum quam in elit dapibus imperdiet. Integer lobortis nec dolor sit amet accumsan. Sed nec faucibus mi, scelerisque mollis erat. Vivamus eu sapien ornare, posuere mi nec, mollis metus. Aenean convallis est ipsum, eget dignissim leo tincidunt eget. Praesent malesuada dolor vel lacus malesuada, at fermentum nunc eleifend. Integer est metus, dapibus sit amet enim in, posuere aliquam lorem. Vivamus convallis neque at odio convallis, ut sodales erat ultricies. Quisque et enim ac enim imperdiet consectetur. Etiam eget lectus nec lorem congue dictum. Nulla facilisi.

        Quisque ligula dolor, pharetra et ante nec, blandit interdum risus. Mauris ultrices malesuada sem, a luctus diam auctor in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque purus magna, laoreet id malesuada non, blandit sed diam. Vivamus blandit faucibus mattis. Aliquam semper faucibus erat eu mollis. Donec eleifend leo lacus, sed aliquet nisi consequat ac.

        Morbi dictum pharetra feugiat. In nec turpis dolor. Mauris consectetur hendrerit scelerisque. Aenean eleifend dui ac augue varius porttitor at a leo. Fusce semper mollis vulputate. Praesent libero enim, congue eget tellus vitae, mattis tempor turpis. Fusce cursus ligula quam, eget iaculis leo ullamcorper eget. Nam laoreet quam pulvinar, egestas justo id, cursus eros. Pellentesque congue porttitor pretium.

        Suspendisse mattis sapien sed magna tempus ultrices. Nullam porta sagittis nulla ut venenatis. Nulla faucibus elementum elementum. Integer sed consectetur elit, quis elementum dolor. Donec dapibus aliquam orci eu pretium. Aliquam vel fermentum nunc. Duis augue mauris, semper at neque ac, aliquet mattis augue. Suspendisse pulvinar vehicula semper. Aenean purus orci, pharetra vel sollicitudin quis, tincidunt ac dolor.

        Duis nibh tellus, iaculis vel venenatis sed, condimentum ac est. Sed ac imperdiet neque. Phasellus et euismod lorem. Nunc hendrerit orci mattis, tincidunt quam vel, varius mauris. Phasellus venenatis malesuada congue. Nam ut nunc eros. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque facilisis massa a tortor imperdiet ullamcorper eget convallis nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Nam a congue est. Praesent id ante dui. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed eget metus sit amet arcu pellentesque molestie ac eget mauris. Nullam adipiscing odio at interdum porttitor. Proin magna mi, facilisis ac rhoncus ac, gravida ut lacus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus convallis neque ut turpis volutpat pretium. Donec luctus vel lectus eget condimentum. Aliquam interdum dignissim neque, eu pulvinar erat porta sit amet. Nam urna lectus, rhoncus eu ante ac, lobortis pretium velit. Phasellus vestibulum quam in elit dapibus imperdiet. Integer lobortis nec dolor sit amet accumsan. Sed nec faucibus mi, scelerisque mollis erat. Vivamus eu sapien ornare, posuere mi nec, mollis metus. Aenean convallis est ipsum, eget dignissim leo tincidunt eget. Praesent malesuada dolor vel lacus malesuada, at fermentum nunc eleifend. Integer est metus, dapibus sit amet enim in, posuere aliquam lorem. Vivamus convallis neque at odio convallis, ut sodales erat ultricies. Quisque et enim ac enim imperdiet consectetur. Etiam eget lectus nec lorem congue dictum. Nulla facilisi.

        Quisque ligula dolor, pharetra et ante nec, blandit interdum risus. Mauris ultrices malesuada sem, a luctus diam auctor in. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque purus magna, laoreet id malesuada non, blandit sed diam. Vivamus blandit faucibus mattis. Aliquam semper faucibus erat eu mollis. Donec eleifend leo lacus, sed aliquet nisi consequat ac.

        Morbi dictum pharetra feugiat. In nec turpis dolor. Mauris consectetur hendrerit scelerisque. Aenean eleifend dui ac augue varius porttitor at a leo. Fusce semper mollis vulputate. Praesent libero enim, congue eget tellus vitae, mattis tempor turpis. Fusce cursus ligula quam, eget iaculis leo ullamcorper eget. Nam laoreet quam pulvinar, egestas justo id, cursus eros. Pellentesque congue porttitor pretium.

        Suspendisse mattis sapien sed magna tempus ultrices. Nullam porta sagittis nulla ut venenatis. Nulla faucibus elementum elementum. Integer sed consectetur elit, quis elementum dolor. Donec dapibus aliquam orci eu pretium. Aliquam vel fermentum nunc. Duis augue mauris, semper at neque ac, aliquet mattis augue. Suspendisse pulvinar vehicula semper. Aenean purus orci, pharetra vel sollicitudin quis, tincidunt ac dolor.

        Duis nibh tellus, iaculis vel venenatis sed, condimentum ac est. Sed ac imperdiet neque. Phasellus et euismod lorem. Nunc hendrerit orci mattis, tincidunt quam vel, varius mauris. Phasellus venenatis malesuada congue. Nam ut nunc eros. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque facilisis massa a tortor imperdiet ullamcorper eget convallis nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Nam a congue est. Praesent id ante dui. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed eget metus sit amet arcu pellentesque molestie ac eget mauris. Nullam adipiscing odio at interdum porttitor. Proin magna mi, facilisis ac rhoncus ac, gravida ut lacus.
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer Content
    </div>
</div>
```